# When should I use div tags when I already have the option for dividing page with Table tag

Tags: html

When should I use div tags when I already have the option for dividing page with Table tag

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/83073/why-not-use-tables-for-layout-in-html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting up the layout using table tag is now obsolete when you can use the div tags with nice css features, and hence position them to the level of pixels as you like and   define there position on the page as absoulte, fixed, relative etc.

Comment: with html5 even the basic divisions header, section, footer, aside etc are already defined..

Answer (score 4):

**Because tables are for tabular data, divs are for layout.**

Comment: What do u mean by layout exactly

Comment: Layout elements, i.e. header, navigation, footer.

Comment: Layout is what holds whole page, tabular data is one elements in content area (mostly).

Answer (score 0):

It depends on who is looking at your page.

If it's just you, then it doesn't matter. Do what you want.

If the wider world is going to see your page(s) then use mark-up as it's meant to be used.

Tables are for tabular data, as Marko says, so only use them for that. Divs allow you to divide up your content in to a logical structure that can be styled by CSS, **OR NOT**.

It's important to realise that there are some ways of using the web that are not visual, such as screen readers and Braille interfaces.

If you use tables for layout you are impeding the use of your page by people/processes who are not experiencing it with eyes.

Comment: Also, in some circumstances, tables can be slower to render, although I doubt that's much of a consideration these days.